# Allow Comma in Input Field with Type Number in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, angular-material, material-design

In my application are Input Fields with Number Types. If I type in the numbers manually then I can give in numbers with a comma seperator (20,99) as well as numbers with a dot seperator (20.99).

But if I read the numbers via JSON from another resource and bind these values via ngModel, I get the following error:

> The specified value "2,5" is not a valid number. The value must match to the >following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

That doesnt make sense for me. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? I want to accept comma numbers as well as dot numbers.

Number-Field:

```html
     <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'inputNumber'"
      style="text-align: right; margin-top: 30px;" [ngStyle]="element.style"
      matTooltip="{{element.tooltip}}" matTooltipClass="toolTipClass">

      <span matPrefix>{{element.prefix}}&nbsp;</span>
      <input
            id="{{element.elementId}}"
            #focusable
            matInput
            type="number"
            [placeholder]="element.placeholder"
            [(ngModel)]="formControlService.dialogDaten[element.elementId]"
            (focus)="formControlService.setFocusDurchTastatur(sektion)"
            (blur)="formControlService.disableFocusDurchTastatur(sektion)"
            >
            <span matSuffix>{{element.suffix}}&nbsp;</span>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Expected result:

No matter if I read in the values manually or automatically. In Both ways should the same seperator accepted.

Comment: Are you sure, you are able to type comma into the input field whose type is number?

Comment: Yes, no letters, but comma and dots

Comment: Is it maybe a  culture issue?

Comment: Could be. I live in Germany, here are Commas used as decimal delimiter. But not Dots. Why are both allowed via UI and just DOTS via code. thats confusing

Comment: Usually you can also use `,` e.g. in US as 1000 delimiter like `1,000.25`. Maybe that's the reason why it is allowed. 2,5 would then be an irregular number in en-US. When you enter _1,000.25_ is it then accepted as valid number?

Comment: Yes, the 1000 delimiter is accepted as well. But I can also put in ",,," which makes no sense. It seems, there is no validation of the input. It just blocks anything else than numbers, comma and dots at time of input.

Comment: Update: When I speaking about is accepted then I mean the visual feedback in the UI. If I let write the values on the console, then I get the following results: 11,11 => null; 11.11 => correct; 122.000,29 => correct; So that is all ok. But now can I change the format to the european one?